# Parse query returning objects based on parameter string length (not the parameter I filter by though)

Tags: parse-platform

This has me stumped and I'm pulling my hair out here.

The simple query below finds speeches for the current user:

```
var _debug = function(cb) {
  console.log('_debug')
  var DebugParseObject = Parse.Object.extend("Speech");
  var debugQuery = new Parse.Query(DebugParseObject);
  debugQuery.equalTo("user", _getCurrentUser()); // Incorrect results only occurs when I set the user with this line
  debugQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
      cb(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
};
```

The speech object class has the following extra  columns

- title
- body
- speech_id
- user (pointer)

Here is the weird part: **The query will only return the speeches whose body is a string less than about 1000 characters**.

As in, I can have Speech A, with a 500 character string in the body field. It will be returned as one of the speeches. BUT if I increase Speech A's body string to about 1500 characters, it will NOT be returned any longer.

I can't understand why.

Some further points

1. It's only when I filter by the user. If I search for all speeches or query by a different parameter (e.g. title), then the correct amount is returned
2. This used to work fine yesterday and before
3. I manually deleted a user earlier (removed the row from the table), while their linked speeches still existed
4. I changed those speeches' users value from the deleted user id to a new users id
5. The speeches appear to have the correct user
6. I tried re-saving the user object on the speech's user property and it didn't do anything

Any help will be great! I feel like I've corrupted the user class when I deleted the user row. But I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The query syntax looks solid and you should be well within the storage limitations of Parse. In case you're curious, there's no explicit limit on string length, but Parse Objects are limited to 128k (except for Parse Files of course).

My guess is that something has gone awry when copying over a different user in place of the one you deleted. Manually changing data and pointers within the browser is always risky and prone to errors.

Comment: I just discovered that. I was thinking 'if the ui allows me to do it, it must be safe'. I created a new app and everything works fine (thankfully we don't have many users yet). So it must be something to do with the users